# Edit Media queries CSS with event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I have an unordered list `<ul>` that I would like to add an event listener too
if it fits a certain media query.

The original css :

```css
        @media (max-width: 414px) {
          transition: all 3s ease-out;
          height: 0px;
          display: none;
        }
```

the eventlistener function :

```js
    if(window.matchMedia("max-width: 414px")) {
      console.log(list.style.height);
      console.log(list.style.display);
      list.style.height = 'auto'
      list.style.display = 'unset'
    }
```

HELP : the transition seems not to be working & the console log for list.style.height & list.style.display is both empty ''

Comment: Your @media rule doesn't have a style rule inside it. Where are those style declarations going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transition won't work because you are changing display from/to `none`. In addition, you need to transition the `height` between numeric values (`auto` doesn't count).

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 414px) {
    transition: all 3s ease-out;
    height: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 414px)").matches) {
  list.style.height = list.style.height + 'px'; // set the exact height
}
```

Comment: You missed the fact that the `max-width: 414px` expression must be in parentheses, and that the matchMedia() function returns an MQL which contains a .matches property which should be the one tested in the condition, as Shadow Fiend pointed out.

Comment: hi thanks ! i fixed it with your help on the display part ! yeah it doesnt work with transition and transform, "display". But after making my <ul> to be able to make transformation in scale, the li inside it do not transform the same way ... hmmm .. ul appears by sliging down, li just fly in

Answer (score 2):

Its not working and your console is empty because of this line

```
if(window.matchMedia("max-width: 414px")) {
```

It must be

```
 if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 414px)").matches) {
```

And transition is not working with `display:none` and `height:auto`..

You can try `opacity` instead of `display`.

I made a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14p6j5qf/1/)..

And try to look at the console you can see that its not empty anymore.